# How can a component at designtime determine the project directory

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, components, design-time

I write a component which should store some information relative to the project directory. Every time a property of my component is changed it should write a file. So how can a component determine the current project directory at design time.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I want to generate a delphi source file every time a property of my component is changed, so that I always get the latest version when I compile my code. Think of it as a kind of code generator.

At the moment I set whole path and filename where the source should be stored but I prefer a relative path to the project (or the form/datamodule which contains my component) to make it easier to copy the project on different developer machines.

Comment: In C++, we would just set some constant in the project that can be used by the sources. Such a complex and unreliable thing to do in Delphi :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the hints. Open Tools API is the way to go and using the Open Tools API from a component on a form at designtime is possible.

So here is my solution:

I need two units, one for the component and one for registering the component and the code which use the Open Tools API.

Here comes the component unit:

```
unit TestLabels;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Windows, Controls, StdCtrls;

type
  TTestLabel = class(TLabel)
  private
    FTestProperty: Boolean;
    procedure SetTestProperty(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure Changed;
  published
    property TestProperty: Boolean read FTestProperty write SetTestProperty;
  end;

var
  OnGetUnitPath: TFunc;

implementation

{ TTestLabel }

procedure TTestLabel.Changed;
begin
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
     Exit; // I only need the path at designtime

  if csLoading in ComponentState then
     Exit; // at this moment you retrieve the unit path which was current before

  if not Assigned(OnGetUnitPath) then
    Exit;

  // only for demonstration
  Caption := OnGetUnitPath;
  MessageBox(0, PChar(ExtractFilePath(OnGetUnitPath)), 'Path of current unit', 0);
end;

procedure TTestLabel.SetTestProperty(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FTestProperty  Value then
  begin
    FTestProperty := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Here is the unit for registering the component and the call to the Open Tools API:

```
unit TestLabelsReg;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, TestLabels;

procedure register;

implementation

uses
  ToolsAPI;

function GetCurrentUnitPath: String;
var
  ModuleServices: IOTAModuleServices;
  Module: IOTAModule;
  SourceEditor: IOTASourceEditor;
  idx: integer;

begin
  Result := '';
  SourceEditor := nil;

  if SysUtils.Supports(BorlandIDEServices, IOTAModuleServices,
    ModuleServices) then
  begin
    Module := ModuleServices.CurrentModule;

    if System.Assigned(Module) then
    begin
      idx := Module.GetModuleFileCount - 1;

      // Iterate over modules till we find a source editor or list exhausted
      while (idx >= 0) and not SysUtils.Supports(Module.GetModuleFileEditor(idx), IOTASourceEditor, SourceEditor) do
        System.Dec(idx);

      // Success if list wasn't ehausted.
      if idx >= 0 then
        Result := ExtractFilePath(SourceEditor.FileName);
    end;

  end;

end;

procedure register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TTestLabel]);
  TestLabels.OnGetUnitPath := GetCurrentUnitPath;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your GetCurrentUnitPath does not compile (at least the boolean expression for the while loop doesn't) and the while loop will never end. But the idea is interesting though, so I did upvote your answer.

Comment: @Jeroen: Thank you for pointing this out. The stackoverflow.com editor cropped the line "while not ((idx < 0) or SysUtils.Supports(Module.GetModuleFileEditor(idx), IOTASourceEditor, SourceEditor) do". I have adjust the condition of the while-loop so stackoverflow.com shows it correct. By the way, the CurrentUnitPath is extracted (with modifications) from the DUnit wizzard which comes with delphi.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with delphi 7, the ToolsAPI unit defines a getActiveProject function which returns the IOTAProject interface of the current project.

The fileName property of IOTAProject returns the full path of the main source file of the project (typically the .dpr file).

So, in many cases, it's possible to use a simple instruction such as:

```
if csDesigning in componentState then
    appFolderPath := extractFilePath( getActiveProject.fileName ) 
else
    appFolderPath := extractFilePath( application.exeName );
```

(and there's no need of using two units as in Heinz's example above)

Comment: Convenient :-)
I just created an TComponentEditor that edit resources (*.rc) with this. The relative path to the resource is converted to absolute path with this base.

Comment: Be careful with this solution: ActiveProject is not necessarily the "owning" project, consequently, you are going into troubles if RadStudio has a group with several projects open. I went through this, and it's painful.

Answer (score 2):

A component cannot access your source path, because a component is placed in your application and run as a part of your application out of Delphi IDE.

If you want to have access to project path, or automate any process inside IDE; you have to write an IDE expert using OpenTools API, not a component.

Comment: This is not always true: Components also runs in the Designer. Obviously, the source path is not available at application runtime, but it's still useful to have the project path at design time (e.g. to retrieve resources in an editor).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can.  You can determine the directory your EXE is running in easily enough, but your component at design-time is running as a part of the IDE.  I doubt there's a way for the component to access project information through the IDE.

Comment: That is not what I want hear. :-) I hoped that I can access the design API of the IDE from my component.

Comment: Take a look at OTAPI, which can access the design API of the IDE, but I don't think you can mix OTAPI functionality in with components on a form.

Comment: @Heinz: Not from your component, as Mason said. You can from an IDE Expert using the Open Tools API (OTAPI).

Comment: Mixing OTAPI with components is possible (see my solution)

Answer (score 1):

see

http://www.gexperts.org/otafaq.html#project

and then

www.href.com/pub/sw/ProjectOptions.html

may be it helps

Comment: The link to gexperts otafaq was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had A little bit different objective: how to know where the project exe will be at design time, so that the application at runtime can share some files with the design time functionality.

So, I combined the two best answers and created the following function to be used in applications:

```
unit MyUtils;

interface

function GetProjectTargetPath: string;

var

  _GetProjectTargetPath: TFunc<string>;

...
implementation

function GetProjectTargetPath: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Assigned(_GetProjectTargetPath) then
    Result := _GetProjectTargetPath;
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Result);
end;
```

and then in the component registration unit (which I have separate and linked only to the design time package):

```
unit MyUtils;

...
implementation

function GetProjectTargetPath: String;
begin
  Result := ExtractFilePath( GetActiveProject.ProjectOptions.TargetName );
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  ...
  MyUtils._GetProjectTargetPath := GetProjectTargetPath;
end;
```

Thus avoiding the actual unit to depend on ToolsAPI.

MyUtils.GetProjectTargetPath returns an empty string at runtime, which corresponds to the application exe-directory in practice.