# How to determine the path of a DFM where the custom TComponent is?

Tags: delphi, designer, tcustomcontrol

Within a custom `TComponent`, I need to get the path of the `*.dfm` or `*.pas` file where the `TComponent` is used.  Obviously, this is only required at design-time.

### Context

Similar to a previous question:
[How to detect the dfm/project path from a custom control while in the designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213860)

> I created a custom TControl similar to TImageCollection but with a shared database of images for all the application. For this, the control reads a project meta-file which is an XML containing the list of images to include in the image collection. When in the designer, images are read directly from the image files, but at runtime, images are in the resource (*.res) file generated during the compilation.
>
> ```
> if csDesigning in Self.ComponentState then
>   loadImagesFromFiles(...)
> else
>   loadImagesFromResource(...)
> ```

In the previous version (for the other question linked above), I tried to get the path of the project, and while this seems not possible, I found a way to get the path to the active project. However, this is very problematic when the IDE has several projects open.

I decided to switch to another approach, where I use a path relative to the DFM where the component is used. This should be more reliable.

Unfortunately, it seems not that easy for a custom `TComponent` placed on a DFM to know where that DFM is located.

### Solutions (half)

I tried several solutions with `IOTA`, but could not get anything working yet.

The approach [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433580) returns the path to the `TComponent` itself, not to the DFM where it's used.

I managed to iterate Modules following the same strategy, but finding which Module contains the given `TComponent` is not trivial:

```
function GetCurrentDfmPath(AComponent: TComponent): String;
var
  ModuleServices: IOTAModuleServices;
  Module: IOTAModule;
  idx: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  SourceEditor := nil;

  if SysUtils.Supports(BorlandIDEServices, IOTAModuleServices,
    ModuleServices) then
  begin
    for idx := 0 to ModuleServices.ModuleCount - 1 do
    begin
      Module := ModuleServices.Modules[idx];

      // Needs to match the module that contains AComponent.?

    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could solve it more low-tech by creating a TImageDatabase component, that holds just the path you need, and of which the user is supposed to have just one in the application, and let all instances of your similar-to-TImageCollection component have a reference to that TImageDatabase component? It would be a quite typical pattern, and would make the solution simple.

Comment: Note that to make this to work, that path needs to be absolute, and that imply that each developer, but also each clone of the project need to have a custom value for this path. More, when that project (if it's a package) is included in another project, things become really  complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At design-time, your component's `Owner` should be the parent Form (all components dropped on a Form at design-time are owned by the Form by default).

If your component is derived from `TControl`, it can alternatively find its parent Form by using the [`Forms.GetParentForm()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.GetParentForm) function.

`TCustomForm` has a [`Designer`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Designer) property of type [`IDesignerHook`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.IDesignerHook) that is non-nil at design-time.

Query the `IDesignerHook` for [`IDesigner`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.IDesigner) using the `as` operator ([do not use a hard cast!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637832/)).

`IDesigner` has a [`ModuleFileNames()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.IDesigner60.ModuleFileNames) method to retrieve the filenames associated with the object being designed, which in this case will be the `TCustomForm` so the `FormFileName` parameter will output the filename of the `.dfm` (VCL) or `.xfm` (FMX).

Comment: Is it doable with a TComponent? or should I make my TComponent a TControl?
It's an acceptable trade-off, but for a non-visible element, TComponent seems better option.

Comment: The `owner` is a `TDataModule` which is not a `TCustomForm` and the next owner is `DataModuleForm` which is a `TCustomForm`. However, `ownerForm.Designer` is `nil` at design time.

Comment: Try the `FindRootDesigner()` function in the `Classes` unit. It takes a `TPersistent` (which `TComponent` derives from) and returns an `IDesignerNotify`, which you can then cast to `IDesigner` with the `as` operator.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, and still having some issues within DataModules, I finally implemented a solution like the following:

```
function GetCurrentDfmPath(aComponent: TComponent): string;
var
  form: TCustomForm;
  parent: TComponent;
  designerHook: IDesignerHook;
  impl, intf, formFile: string;

  ModuleServices: IOTAModuleServices;
  Module: IOTAModule;
  Editor: IOTAFormEditor;
  i: Integer;
begin

  // Test if we can get the IDesigner
  parent := aComponent.owner;
  while Assigned(parent.owner) and not (parent is TCustomForm) do
  begin
    parent := parent.owner;
  end;

  if Assigned(parent) and (parent is TCustomForm) then
  begin
    form := parent as TCustomForm;

    designerHook := form.Designer;
    if Assigned(designerHook) and Assigned(designerHook as IDesigner) then
    begin
      (designerHook as IDesigner).ModuleFileNames(impl, intf, formFile);
      Result := formFile;
    end;
  end;

  // If not found (maybe we are using a DataModule), attempt another solution.
  if (Result='') then
  begin
    parent := aComponent.owner;
    while Assigned(parent.owner) and not (parent is TDataModule) do
    begin
      parent := parent.owner;
    end;

    if Supports(BorlandIDEServices, IOTAModuleServices, ModuleServices) then
    begin
      // Iterate through all modules open in the IDE
      for i := 0 to ModuleServices.ModuleCount - 1 do
      begin
        Module := ModuleServices.Modules[i];
            
        if SameText(ExtractFileName(Module.FileName), parent.UnitName  + '.pas') then
        begin
          Result := Module.FileName;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Result := ExtractFilePath(Result);
end;
```